# How to pipe JACK output into a program

Tags: sound

So, I installed qjackctl just for Discord.
How do I make qjackctl output to discord. 
PS - I am using jack-rack to change my voice.
Here is what my connections look like:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work using Cadence.

Basically, Discord uses PulseAudio, which is not compatible with JACK. So Cadence redirects PulseAudio into JACK.

[image: Catia connections]

As you can see I have my mic into the Jack Rack, which is going into PulseAudio, so Discord detects it